# How to configure T4 template to generate classes in different project

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, t4, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using new Entity Framework 4.1 Model first approach that makes use of T4 templates to generate classes from visual model.

Can I configure that T4 templates to create POCO classes and Context classes (or at generally whatever they generate) in another project?

**Please note** that I don't want to move T4 template (file with .tt) to another project and then just change the template to EDMX file in persistence project. I want it to really generate that classes in another project then the location of template. Is that possible ?

Thank you for answers

---

**Notes:** this is no duplicate of question [Generate POCO classes in different project to the project with Entity Framework model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464909/generate-poco-classes-in-different-project-to-the-project-with-entity-framework-m) as author there wanted just what I don't: move the whole template together with classes generated.

I fully understand that moving the whole template will not mean that the other project will become persistence aware. Still, I have my reasons why I don't want it in the same project with POCO classes.

Comment: Can you explain your reasons? I'm affraid that what you want is not the part of T4 template but the custom tool executing the template logic and modifing the project file (adding new files).

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka The reasons are more about my personal preference then anything else. I have my system on how to organize projects and files in it and I'm used to it so I can quickly find what I need even number of files grows. I like to keep files that I have made together in some projects, files that other people have made in another ones and generated code in separate projects. T4 templates are disturbing this concept because I want to add some code to the same project there POCO classes will be :(

Comment: Why dont you just add generated cs file inside your other projects as file links?

Comment: @Akash Kava that might be a solution if what I ask is not possible...

Comment: **Are these projects part of the same solution maybe?**

Comment: @Robert Koritnik Yes they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Multiple projects sharing the same templates

Whenever I use shared T4 templates I:

1. create a solution folder
2. put my generation T4 template in it and set its extension to **ttinclude**
3. add additional T4 templates to my projects wherever needed but with **tt** extension
4. depending on template functionality, they may only have to reference the shared **ttinclude** template as in [this example of mine](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/generate-enum-of-database-lookup-table.html) that I use to generate enum types of database lookup tables;

If you're using provided templates you will have to modify them a bit to make this work, because they will have to reference EDMX file on a different location than default. You can as well provide this path as a local variable that you override in your per-project template so it will use the overridden path instead of default defined in the **ttinclude** file.

Comment: this doesn't really help for project types that don't support T4, I'd like to generate files into other projects in the solution without any T4 in the target project.