# Entity Framework 5 stopped running T4 templates files on save

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, t4, entity-framework-5

At work we just upgraded to Entity Framework 5. Our EDMX file now has a couple other nodes beneath it:

```
EntityContainer.Context.tt
```

which contains the generated DbContext object and

```
EntityContainer.tt
```

which contains the entities themselves.

For a short period, adding an entity in EF was automatically regenerating the tt (T4 Templates) when we would save the EDMX file. Now all of a sudden we have to right-click the T4 templates and select "Run Custom Tool" to get them to regenerate the .cs files for the context or entities.

Any ideas how this might have happened?

### Update

In the EDMX the property "Transform Related Text Templates On Save" is set to true and the problem is still happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your EDMX in a sub-folder of your project? If so, the good news is that you didn't do anything wrong. The bad news is that this is a known issue...check my blog post about it. http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/watch-out-for-vs2012-edmx-code-generation-special-case/.

Two work arounds for the time being:

1) move the edmx into the main project folder
2) explicitly force the code gen as needed

Comment: Thank you. Yes it is in a `\Entities' folder. Do you think a fix will be available soon or is this at a level that is difficult to fix on the fly?

Comment: There is another workaround option that I believe is a little cleaner. See my answer :)

Comment: Also note that you can force the code gen solution wide using the Transform All Templates button.
- In VS2010, you'll find this on the Solution Explorer toolbar.
- In VS2012, it's on the build menu or build toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually another workaround option. I discovered this error because I upgraded an EF 4 EDMX to EF 5 by adding `EF 5.x DbContext Generator` to the project, which added T4 templates to the existing EDMX.

However, in the project file it did not mark them as `DependentUpon` the EDMX file so they did not appear under the EDMX node. Instead they appeared side-by-side with the EDMX in the folder. T4 generation worked fine until I manually went in and added the `DependentUpon` nodes in the project file.

Observe: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-boB5GhqfUI

Comment: nice. I don't like the "move them out of the sub folder option" anyway. If you've put them in a sub folder, you've done that for a reason! I can't see the video. The resolution is SO high and the font SO small and when I go full screen it's blurry. Tip from someone who does lots of screencasts...1024x768 FTW for videos with visual studio :)

Comment: You should be able to select 1080p and 720p on the video quality. I'm able to see it just fine, you sure it's too difficult to see at full screen and higher quality?

Comment: Here is a video at 1024 x 768 for you :)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHKSZximF8w