# Moving EF POCOs to separate project compilation errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, poco, ef-database-first

I have two separate projects, one that holds EF pocos and the MyDb.tt file that generates them.  That project compiles fine.

The remaining project that holds the MyDb.edmx will not compile.  It has many errors saying "could not found"

The errors are coming from MyDb.Context.cs from lines like this:

```
public DbSet<Gender> Genders { get; set; }
```

If I add a using statement e.g. "MyPocosProj" to the top of this file the errors go away.  Is this what I need to do or ??

BTW: I followed the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464909/generate-poco-classes-in-different-project-to-the-project-with-entity-framework) question