# Map SQL Query results into entities (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, orm, automap

Is there a way to automap a query into a class in C# in order to strong type the query results? I don't want to access to query result with a DataTable, specifying manually the Column Name anymore.

Comment: Use Entity Framework maybe .. or other ORM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favourite question. Use [QueryFirst](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst). Write your SQL in the SQL editor window, syntax validated as you type, then QueryFirst will generate the C# wrapper to execute it, with strongly typed inputs and outputs. And there are numerous other benefits :-) SqlServer, MySql and Postgres support built in. Others easy to add. Disclaimer : I wrote QueryFirst.

Comment: the tool seems fit perfect to my needs but why all classes generated are empty even if tables are full of query results?

Comment: How do you mean empty classes? You've installed the tool? You've created your design time and runtime data sources? You've written a query, that runs, and so you can inspect the generated wrapper and poco? You call Execute() and get empty instances ? How many ?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Ok then make sure your QfDefaultConnection has a provider="System.Data.SqlClient".

Comment: this is my QfRuntimeConnection                                                                
class QfRuntimeConnection
    {
        public static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["QfRuntimeConnection"];
        }
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132111/discussion-between-crk-and-user1585345).

Answer (score 3):

There is couple of options:

`EntityFramework` - powerful and heavyweight. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx

`Dapper` - lightweight - mostly mapper https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/212274/A-Look-at-Dapper-NET

If you need only mapping of stored procedures, queries etc, Dapper is good way to go, as it's basically adding extension methods to `connection` object. It cannot create database etc as Entity Framework but it all really depends on needs.

Comment: How to use Dapper to automatically create a class from query results?

Comment: Nothing can do it for you. As it's not anyhow good practice. You can generate classes bye EntityFramework based on existing Database (but that is not on runtime). These days you should be creating classes and using EF to create database out of them not other way round.

Comment: The fact that is "not on runtime" is good. In this way I can strong type my DataTable. If it create class at runtime I can't do this. I'm right?

Comment: in ORM there is not more DataTable, it's Classes to Database objects relation. DataTable is already a moment where you skip ORM.

Comment: Why `DataTable's are so important for you?

Comment: I make it simple: I want to automatically create a class from a query at design time in order to use this class in my code. I don't want to do this at runtime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131793/discussion-between-madox-and-crk).

Comment: @MadOX - "Nothing can do it for you". 
QueryFirst can do it for you, and I would say it's very good practice! Not everyone is happy with EF. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/). It's an easy and user-friendly way to map a `DataTable` to a `List<object>` of your specification.
You can find an article which talks about it (including sample code) [here](http://www.geekytidbits.com/automapper-with-datatables/).
If you want to automize the process, you can use [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) objects which don't require you to create specific classes for every `DataTable` that you're using.
Hope this helped!

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer. I want to automatize the process, in the artcile you posted he tells to create a Class that matches Column of DataTable but I want to do it automatically (not manually create the class).

Comment: Good, but this do all at runtime , I'm right? So I can't strong type the DataTable.

Comment: You would do something like: `List<dynamic> objects = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<object>>(dataTable.CreateDataReader());` The DataTable has to be strongly typed, but the objects mapped don't need to be. So, yes it'll be done at runtime.

Comment: Maybe my bad English don't help. If I do what you tell, how can I have the autocompletion to access at a specific Column Name if this will evaluate at runtime?

Comment: Autocomplete doesn't work for dynamic objects. You'll need to make sure you're not making any errors whilst programming manually. e.g. `objects[0].testVariable = 5;` will be evaluated at runtime as it's an anonymous type.

Comment: Is there a way to do this at design time? Automatically create class for the query (I don't know how to right explain that) like EF do when you connect to a DataBase and he automatically create classes in order to use them with the autocompletion, strong typing all? @Nathangrad

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but if you want to use Entity Framework for that, then that would probably be the best option for you. See MadOX's answer for that solution.

Comment: EF create class at design-time. I want this but not from DataBase, but only from query results

Answer (score 0):

There is a helpful library on LINQ to DB

"LINQ to DB is the fastest LINQ database access library offering a simple, light, fast, and type-safe layer between your POCO objects and your database."

https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db

Comment: Does it create classes at design time?

Comment: No it does not... yry here is talks about what your looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464909/generate-poco-classes-in-different-project-to-the-project-with-entity-framework